# Array initialization in Managed C++

Tags: .net, c++-cli, managed-c++

I wish to declare and initialize a 1D managed array of items.

If it was C# code, I would write it like this:

```
VdbMethodInfo[] methods = new VdbMethodInfo[] {
    new VdbMethodInfo("Method1"),
    new VdbMethodInfo("Method2")
};
```

I am trying to write (well, actually, I'm writing a program generate) the same thing in managed C++...

So far I have:

```
typedef array<VdbMethodInfo^, 1> MethodArray;
// How do I avoid pre-declaring the size of the array up front?
MethodArray^ methods = gcnew MethodArray(2);
methods[0] = gcnew VdbMethodInfo("Method1");
methods[1] = gcnew VdbMethodInfo("Method2");
```

There are two problems with this:

1. It's more verbose
2. It requires me to declare the size of the array up front, which is inconvenient for my code generator

Is there an "array initialization" syntax for GC arrays in Managed C++? What is the correct syntax? Is there a good web link for this and other similar questions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The C++/CLI array declare & initialize syntax is not dissimilar from that in C#.  Here's an example...

```
array<String^>^ myArray = gcnew array<String^> {"first",  "second"};
```

Comment: The C++/CLI decompiler for reflector was missing the gcnew and the array type in the declaration for some reason. Adding that fixed the issue. Thanks. http://www.sandpapersoftware.com/Main/Reflector.html

Answer (score 0):

MSDN page on managed array syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4c4dw6(VS.80).aspx