# Bug in Array initialization in Managed C++ (followup)

Tags: .net, c++, managed-c++

Following up from my previous question.

Can anyone explain why the following code compiles without any errors:

```
typedef array<VdbMethodInfo^> MethodArray;
typedef array<VdbParameterInfo^> ParameterArray;
ParameterArray^ parameters = gcnew ParameterArray {
    gcnew VdbParameterInfo("name", "string", "Paul")};
MethodArray^ methods = gcnew MethodArray {
    gcnew VdbMethodInfo("createTable", parameters)
};
```

Yet this gives me "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'VdbParameterInfo ^' to 'VdbMethodInfo ^"

```
typedef array<VdbMethodInfo^> MethodArray;
typedef array<VdbParameterInfo^> ParameterArray;
MethodArray^ methods = gcnew MethodArray {
    gcnew VdbMethodInfo("createTable", gcnew ParameterArray {
        gcnew VdbParameterInfo("name", "string", "Paul")};
    )
};
```

All I've done is attempt to "nest" the parameter array inside the method array initialization... Not directly mind - VdbMethodInfo's constructor takes, as a second argument, a ParameterArray.

It seems to imply that managed C++ array initialization expects any recursive nesting to have the same type... (i.e. I think this must be a bug)

Related question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834903/array-initialization-in-managed-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround which makes the syntax cleaner anyway. I use the "..." syntax (Managed C++ equivalent to the C# "params" keyword"):

```
public ref class MetaData
{
    typedef array<VdbMethodInfo^> MethodArray;
    typedef array<VdbParameterInfo^> ParameterArray;
    static ParameterArray^ params(... ParameterArray^ p)
    {
        return p;
    }
public:
    static array<VdbMethodInfo^>^ Instance()
    {
        ParameterArray^ parameters = gcnew ParameterArray { gcnew VdbParameterInfo("name", "string", "Paul")};
        MethodArray^ methods = gcnew MethodArray {
            gcnew VdbMethodInfo("createTable",
                params(gcnew VdbParameterInfo("name", "string", "Paul"),
                       gcnew VdbParameterInfo("age", "number", "25")))
        };

        return methods;
    }
};
```